# Entity Framework 5 Migrations going to production (File System Publishing)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I'm not sure about what changes should I care about when going to production using Migrations and the publish option through File System.
I mean, for example, I guess I should not use any initializer when going to production right? since I might be deleting data there I think I should always get the script and run it in production db. Is this correct?

What about Configuration class?
Should I turn to false AutomaticMigrationsEnabled on each publish?

Is there a better way than modifying the connectionstring in web.config and app.config from dev to production each time I want to publish my code?

Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the perfect answer with Web Config transformations

The idea is to have the Web.Config and Web.< environment >.Config.
Then each Web..Config has for example replacements to the values of the original Web.Config so when we publish the transformation of the environment selected is run and ConnectionString can be changed automatically for the one in production.

[This Introductory Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3nF5jf72q0) is great to get involved with it.
Then there are a lot of tutorials in the Internet and something called SlowCheetah to handle this easier.

Best Regards. Guillermo.